# Is it possible to implicitly get a builder for a collection, as in the old CanBuildFrom?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, implicit

I have some old code which relied on implicit `CanBuildFrom` in order to build a collection of a type specified as a type parameter. Since 2.12, in new collection library, replacement `BuildFrom` doesn't offer a no-arg `Builder` factory method. What I want is the `IterableFactory` for the collection, but these are companion objects, which are not implicit. **Can I somehow port it without introducing my own implicit factory class wrapping a `Factory` for every collection class in the library?** I know that there are many flavours to those factories, but even if I had to add a special case for those accepting implicit evidence, it would still be much better than what I have.

A sensible alternative in new code would probably be to take the `IterableFactory` as a (value) argument instead of relying on explicit type arguments, but it would require changes in too many places, so I'd rather stick to the current architecture and do the boilerplate.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551015/how-to-make-method-return-the-same-generic-as-the-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build a generic collection element-by-element with a `Builder` and without a prior  existing collection, you can use an implicit [`Factory`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Factory.html) argument. For example:

```
import scala.collection.Factory

class Filler[T](makeElement: Int => T) {
  def apply[C[_]](n: Int)(implicit factory: Factory[T, C[T]]): C[T] = {
    val builder = factory.newBuilder
    for (i <- 1 to n) builder += makeElement(i)
    builder.result()
  }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
scala> val fill = new Filler(_.toString)
fill: Filler[String] = Filler@154f8280

scala> fill[Vector](10)
res0: Vector[String] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> fill[Set](10)
res1: Set[String] = HashSet(8, 4, 9, 5, 10, 2, 7, 3, 6, 1)

scala> fill[Array](10).toSeq
res2: Seq[String] = ArraySeq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

There are individual implicit `Factory`s for `String`s and `Array`s provided in the standard library. And for all the `Iterable`s (`List`, `Map`, `Set`, etc.) it works, because the companion objects of `Iterable`s extend the [`IterableFactory`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/IterableFactory.html) class, that provides an `implicit def iterableFactory[A]: Factory[A, CC[A]]` method.

Comment: I feel like a moron. I don't know what I did wrong, because I was sure I did try that. Maybe asked for an implicit `IterableFactory`? Oh well - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use type arguments instead of implicits.

```scala
def listToString[A, CC[x] <: Iterable[x]](
    list: collection.IterableOps[A, CC, CC[A]]
): CC[String] =
  list.map(x => x.toString)
```

[Using it](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/mqXBLjCjRFKmAGOkbl96Zw):

```
listToString(List(1, 2, 3, 4))
-> List(1, 2, 3, 4): List[String]

listToString(Set("foo", "bar", "baz"))
-> Set(foo, bar, baz): scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]
```